# How to Load Extend Number in sql Field Into Select Option Element by PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to load a number of fields in MySQL database to select option element as extending the number by PHP.

for example : 
database `field name = Numbers and value = 25`
and in select option element should be : 1 to 25

to select one of those numbers.

and in other record :
`field name = Numbers and value = 9`
and in select option element should be : 1 to 9

How is it possible?
I'm confused.

Comment: I barely understand what you are asking to be honest, is it just a number in a database that you want to use to put value from 1 to this number in a HTML select tag ?

Comment: @Frankich yes yes yes That's it

Comment: then basically you do your query to get this number, store it into a variable and then do something like `$myHtml = '<select>'; for($i=1; $i<$myNumber+1; $i++) { $myHtml .= "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>" } $myHtml.= '</select>';`

Comment: so what have to be my query?

Comment: Well i don't know, with the informations you gave in the question it would be only supposition. It depends on what you need. Also i could tell you a basic process, but won't provide the code

Comment: @AriaShir please add the code snippets here for the better understanding of the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After 4 hours I finally did it.thanks all
sorry for my bad grammar typing, I`m Iranian and Love All the people of the world Especially Americans and Israelis and others. thanks again, this is my code that i wrote:**

```
<form method="POST" action="/Cart.php" >
<input type="hidden" id="id_pre_List_For_Change_Count" name="id_pre_List_For_Change_Count" value = "<?php echo $row'id_PreList'];?>">
<input type="hidden" id="Count_Filed" name="Count_Filed" value = "<?php echo $row['CurrentCoundAdded'];?>">

<select  id="count_Select_Box" name="count_Select_Box"onchange="this.form.submit();" >
<option selected="selected">
<?php echo $row['CountMany']; ?>
</option>
<?php
for($iz=1; $iz< $row['CurrentCoundAdded']+1; $iz++) {  ?>
<option value=<?php echo $iz ?> > <?php echo $iz ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
</form>
```

[image: the picture:]